# PsExec stucked on 'dotnet test' command

Tags: .net, nunit, psexec

I have an nUnit testing project which i can run locally using:

```
dotnet test MyTests.dll
```

When I run the same command from **Remote**, using **PsExec**, the command gets stucked here:

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.7.1
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait...
>
> A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

The Psexec command on the Remote is:

```
psexec \\<IP> -u <USER> -p <PASSWORD> -n 5 dotnet test C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MyTests.dll
```

I tried adding `-i 1`, `-d`, `-s` or `-h` with no help.

**Note**: Other commands works well with PsExec, such as:

```
psexec \\<IP> -u <USER> -p <PASSWORD> -n 5 calc
```

So it seems related to the dotnet command and not to the PsExec, but on the other hand, running the dotnet locally works well, so I don't know where is the problem...

**Note 2**: I tried to put the dotnet command into a .bat file and call this file in the remote Psexec command, but the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, hope it may help others:

I had to add `-w` which stands for Working Directory.

```
psexec -h -i 1 -w C:\Users\Administrator\Documents \\<IP> -u <USER> -p <PASSWORD> cmd /c "dotnet test MyTests.dll"
```